# How to close Windows console automatically (send CTRL+C to console programatically)?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I have two windows batch scripts, `script1.bat` and `script2.bat`. `script2.bat` is launched from `script1.bat`.

`script1.bat`:

```
...
start call script2.bat
...
```

`script2.bat` has to be closed when user closes `script1.bat`'s console (in another words, `script2.bat` and its console should be closed automatically when `script1.bat` is closed). But `script2.bat` should not be killed, It should be terminated because `script2.bat` has to release database connection. I mean unix signal teminology by using `kill` and `terminate` words. So `scrip2.bat` should not be killed immediately, it should be terminated in way that allows the process to perform nice termination releasing resources and saving state if appropriate.

I made it for unix system and I resolved it as following.

`script1.sh`:

```
...
sh script2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & 
script2_pid="$!" 
trap 'kill -15 $script2_pid' EXIT HUP TERM INT KILL
...
```

How to make it on Windows?

**====EDIT====**

I think that my question is not entirely clear for everyone so I would like to clarify it.

I have java application which connects to JBoss application server. It is tested now and I need to launch both in very convenient way. I prepared batch script (`script1.bat`)which starts both, client application and JBoss application. This script also do another things like setting environment variables. So `script2.bat` is a Jboss `standalone.bat` file in fact. I wouldn't like to edit this file. 
`script1.bat` is my script, it sets environment variables, start JBoss and start my java application.

My script (script1.bat):

```
...
set environment variable 
...
REM start jboss
start standalone.bat
REM start my java application
java ...
```

When user closes Java application, JBoss should also be closed. I need it only for tester's convenient and I know that in production environmnet it should work in another way.
I don't know how to terminate JBoss automatically after user closes my java client application. JBoss connects to H2 database and creates lock on it so if JBoss will be killed immediately then database lock is still there. If JBoss process receives CTRL+C it terminates properly (removes database lock). I want to make it automatically, After user closes java client application, JBoss has to be closed as it receives CTRL+C. 
I have no idea how to do it on Windows. But I did it on linux and I added my code  to this question.

Comment: Widnows? Don't know what that is.

Comment: "hould not be killed, It should be terminated because" ... that does not make sense (unless you are referring to specifics of *nix signals which do not apply to Windows). Better to define your requirements rather than assuming you'll approach the problem in the same way (which won't work).

Comment: Once you start writing such complex code in scripts you are bound to run into insurmountable problems.  Use a real programming language instead.

Comment: Depends on what you haven't shown us - the contents of `script2.bat`. What I would do is to create a file in script1 and have script1 wait while the file is present. In script2, wait for another file to appear. when the second file appears (this is the "shutdown" signal) then script 2 deletes it , performs its shutdown procedure, deletes the file created by script1 and terminates. Script 1 would then take the deletion of the file it created as the signal to proceed.

Comment: You can send a control-C with the GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent() function, but not in batch.

Comment: I prefer batch but If it is impossible in batch I try C++. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CLI is enabled in JBoss then JBoss can be shutdowned by CLI. Following batch shows how to shutdown JBoss

```
...
set environment variable 
...
REM start jboss
start "UNIQUE_NAME" path_to_JBoss\bin\standalone.bat -c standalone.xml
REM start java application
java ...

REM shutdown JBoss by CLI
call path_to_JBoss\bin\jboss-cli.bat --connect ":shutdown"

REM it is just in case. If CLI did not shutdown JBoss, then following line kills JBoss without release of resource.
FOR /f "TOKENS=1,2,*" %%a IN ('tasklist^ /FI  "WINDOWTITLE eq UNIQUE_NAME*" /nh') DO taskkill /pid %%b
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your script makes no sense. `start call script2.bat`?? The combination of `start` and `call` is nonsense. You use either one or the other but not both.

Further I have to disappiont you. There is no way to close a console but keep the code running. You can't even start a hidden console in Windows. Closing the console will instantly stop the execution of the code.

EDIT:

Now I understand what you are asking. Start your first script using

`start "somename" script1.bat`
This will start script1 in a console with "somename" as window title.

In the second script you can use this:

```
:WORKING
REM Do some stuff here
REM and here
REM and here

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('tasklist^ /v^| findstr /i /c:"somename"') DO GOTO WORKING

REM shutdown part
REM close db connections
REM exit script2
```

This part will check if the a console with "somename" in the title is running and if yes reenter the loop. At the end of the loop it alway checks whether script1 is still active. As soon as it's not found the code goes on to the shutdown part.

If you only want to wait for script1 to terminate you can use `PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL` as a 5 (or longer, just replace the 5 ^^) second timeout to avoid busy-waiting:

```
:WORKING
PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('tasklist^ /v^| findstr /i /c:"somename"') DO GOTO WORKING
REM shutdown part
REM close db connections etc.
REM exit script2
```

Comment: `start call script2.bat` makes sense becaouse i use it and it works. It opens new console and launch `sript2.bat` script inside this console.

Comment: I don't want to start hidden console or close console and keep code runing. I want to stop code and close cosnole. But I want to do it automatically (when user closes `script1.bat` console).

Comment: No it doesn't. If you'd just use start it will do just the same.

Comment: It does because I HAVE IT, I USE IT and IT WORKS. Maybe you are right that `start` is sufficient but it works. I am new to batch scripting and I found it on the web.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your question. The only way I can think of is to make script2 run a loop checking whether script1 is running and break the loop and terminate as soon as script1 stops.

Comment: OMG...IT MAKES NO SENSE. You could as well write `start start start start start call call call start call start call start call start start call start`. It's just redundant.

Comment: You could use `tasklist /v` to see all running tasks and `findstr` to check for script2.bat. As long as it's being found script2.bat keeps on working and as soon as it's gone script2.bat terminates.

Comment: I will change `strat call` to `start` for you. You are wrong saying that I can write as well  `start start start start start call call call start call start call start call start start call start`. It opens a lot of consoles and `scripts2.bat` runs only in one. Being accurate It is not the same.

Comment: I've edited my post. Check my solution and tell me whether it works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70209/discussion-between-michaels-and-mariusz).